# Rundeck AWS node plugin user issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, nodes, rundeck

I am using the Rundeck Amazon EC2 node Source to populate my node list. The node list is created successfully, but some of the machines use ubuntu user and the rest use ec2-user, how can I add all the nodes in the same project?

Can Rundeck change the user to ec2-user and retry if the connection fails with ubuntu user.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add the AWS `.pem` key in the key storage and then reference it at the project level: Project Settings > Edit Configuration > Default Node Executor tab (SSH Key Storage Path section) and save. In that way, you can access all nodes directly.

Alternatively, you can add the `rundeck` user public key to the `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on each remote SSH account (or the user that launches Rundeck if you're using a WAR-based installation).